# Swift_TransportException Cannot send message without a sender address

Tags: php, laravel

everyone.

I use laravel6(v6.18.2), and run `php artisan serve`

I tried to send an email with Laravel's default user Authentication. But it gave an error `Swift_TransportException Cannot send message without a sender address`

Here is my code :

```
//.env
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.zoho.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=blabla
MAIL_PASSWORD=blabla
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=blabla@xxx.xxx
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

```
//config/mail.php

'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
    ],
```

Could anyone please tell me why? Thank you.

Comment: Have you set the required in .env file? `MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME= ***USER NAME***
MAIL_PASSWORD= ***PASSWORD***
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls`

Comment: Yeah. I already set them

Comment: Try to remove cache from the system. `php artisan config:cache`

Answer (score 0):

**Clear Cache in Laravel (Terminal)**

*Log in to the system running your Laravel application and open a terminal. Then navigate to your Laravel application code. Here you can issue the commands to clear cache as followings:*

1. Clear Application Cache

   - Run the following command to clear the application cache of the
   - Laravel application.
   - php artisan cache:clear
2. Clear Route Cache

   - To clear route cache of your Laravel application execute the following command from the shell.
   - php artisan route:clear
3. Clear Configuration Cache

   - You can use config:clear to clear the config cache of the Laravel application.
   - php artisan config:clear
4. Clear Compiled Views Cache

   - Also, you may need to clear compiled view files of your Laravel application. To clear compiled view files run the following command from the terminal.
   - php artisan view:clear